# Cloudinary shown incorrect url in Django

Tags: django, cloudinary

I have created a model that uploads `img` to cloudinary, however, shows a wrong URL in the Django template which has 2 'https://' parts inside of it. Please help.

`models.py`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
 img = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100,
                        default='https://res.cloudinary.com/dgdhnbsae/image/upload/vxxxx/product/xxxx.jpg')

def get_img(self):
    return f"{'/media/product/'+self.img}"
```

I have set the related configuration according to the tutorial

`setting.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
xxxx
'cloudinary_storage',
'cloudinary',
```

]

```
CLOUDINARY_STORAGE = {
'CLOUD_NAME': 'xxxx',
'API_KEY': 'xxxxx',
'API_SECRET': 'xxxxx'
```

}

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'cloudinary_storage.storage.MediaCloudinaryStorage'
```

Template:

```
<div class="featured__item__pic set-bg" data-setbg="{{ product.img.url }}">
```

The output:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/xxxx/image/upload/v1/media/https://res.cloudinary.com/vxxxx/image/upload/xxxxx/xxxxx.jpg
```

Comment: Please show the view, especially the context

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood your problem correctly,
youll need to do the below changes

in your model.py file, add below

```
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField
```

instead of using the built in function for the image upload, you'd want to use the cloudinary function.
eg:

```
img = CloudinaryField('attributes')
```

you can later call this in views as usual and then pass it on to your django template. or you can use cloudinary template call, which will allow you to parse additional image manipulation options into the url string.

Some references:
https://jszczerbinski.medium.com/django-web-app-and-images-cloudinary-straightforward-study-ae8b5bb03e37

an easier reference:
https://alphacoder.xyz/image-upload-with-django-and-cloudinary/